# Write the generating function of a sequence as the quotient of two polynomials

Tags: generating-functions

I want to write the generating function of the sequence

$$a_0=2, \;a_1=3, \; a_{n}=2a_{n-1}-2a_{n-2} \; \text{for }n\geq 2$$

as the quotient of two polynomials. But how can I do that? What is the best way?

Comment: If you have a quotient of two polynomials, how can you plug in $n$ and get a sequence?

Comment: I think, I can‘t follow you

Comment: Frederick--- As Ricardo's answer below shows, there is a generating function of rational form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the definition of the generating function:
\begin{align*}
G(x)&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx_n=a_0+a_1x+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}a_nx^n \\
&=a_0+a_1x+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(2a_{n-1}-2a_{n-2})x^n \\
&=a_0+a_1x+2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nx^{n+1}-2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^{n+2} \\
&=a_0+a_1x+2x\left(-a_0+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n\right)-2x^2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n \\
&=a_0+(a_1-2a_0)x+2xG(x)-2x^2G(x)
\end{align*}
Solving for $G(x)$ we obtain
$$
G(x)=\frac{a_0+(a_1-2a_0)x}{1-2x+2x^2}=\frac{2-x}{1-2x+2x^2}.
$$